# Fetch API problems with setInterval()

Tags: ajax, fetch, setinterval

I want to use setInterval () to run this JS Fetch script every 2 seconds as my server content changes frequently for art.txt.  I can't get anything to work.  Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="kdkz"></p>
    <script>
      let file = 'art.txt';

      fetch(file)
        .then((x) => x.text())
        .then((y) => (document.getElementById('kdkz').innerHTML = y));
      setInterval(fetch(), 2000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the fetch into a function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="kdkz"></p>
    <script>
      let file = 'art.txt';

      const handleFetch = () => {
        fetch(file)
          .then((x) => x.text())
          .then((y) => (document.getElementById('kdkz').innerHTML = y));
      };

      setInterval(() => handleFetch(), 2000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```